# PL/SQL Error Happening

Tags: triggers, mutating-table

Select * from cat;

Attempting this

Answer (score 0):

You double-fetch your cursor:

#### Your problem

```
[...]
OPEN UPDATETRIGGER;
FOR UT IN UPDATETRIGGER                  -- This performs fetching into UT
LOOP
    FETCH UPDATETRIGGER                          -- Here You Fetch again..
[...]
```

#### What your loop should look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Display_Update_Message
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON JOBS
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( (old.IsFilled != new.IsFilled) AND (new.isFilled = 'yes'))
DECLARE
    CURSOR UPDATETRIGGER
    IS
        SELECT J.JobID      JobID,
               J.JobName    JobName,
               J.StopDate   StopDate,
               JS.LastName  LastName,
               JS.FirstName FirstName,
               JS.Email     Email
          FROM JOBS  J
               FULL OUTER JOIN JOBAPPLICATIONS JA ON J.JobID = JA.JobID
               FULL OUTER JOIN JOBSEEKERS JS ON JA.JSID = JS.JSID
         WHERE J.JobID = :new.JobID;

    JobID       NUMBER (3);
    JobName     CHAR (30);
    LastName    CHAR (15);
    FirstName   CHAR (15);
    Email       CHAR (30);
    StopDate    DATE;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        'Seekers affected by closing job ' || JobID || ': ' || :new.JobName);

    OPEN UPDATETRIGGER;

    LOOP -- infinite loop
        FETCH UPDATETRIGGER
            INTO JobID,
                 JobName,
                 LastName,
                 FirstName,
                 Email,
                 StopDate;

        EXIT WHEN UPDATETRIGGER%NOTFOUND; -- loop-breaker

        :new.StopDate := SYSDATE;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            '--' || UT.LastName || ', ' || UT.FirstName || '   ' || UT.Email);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE UPDATETRIGGER;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the JOB table in the query. You have the information you require in the :NEW namespace. Not including the JOB table in the query will stop the `ORA-04091` error.

Also you have two sets of cursor control statements. Choose one. I prefer the implicit cursor syntax because it is less typing (and marginally more efficient).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Display_Update_Message 
BEFORE UPDATE ON JOBS
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN ((old.IsFilled != new.IsFilled) AND (new.isFilled = 'yes'))
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seekers affected by closing job ' 
           || :new.JobID || ': ' || :new.JobName);
    FOR UT IN (SELECT JS.LastName
                     , JS.FirstName
                     , JS.Email Email
            FROM JOBAPPLICATIONS JA 
            FULL OUTER JOIN JOBSEEKERS JS ON JA.JSID = JS.JSID
            WHERE JA.JobID = :new.JobID )
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--' || UT.LastName || ', ' || UT.FirstName || '   ' || UT.Email);
    END LOOP;
    :new.StopDate := sysdate;
END;
/
```

Incidentally, I'm not sure why you have FULL OUTER JOIN in your cursor. I would have thought INNER JOIN was the correct solution. Surely you only want Job Seekers who have applied for the job you're closing? However, I have left that in because I don't know your business rules, and anyway I've changed enough of your code already :)